# How may I connect Google Dataproc cluster from Sparklyr?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, sparklyr

I'm new to Spark and GCP. I've tried to connect to it with

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "IP address")
```

but it obviously couldn't work (e.g. there is no authentication).

How should I do that? Is it possible to connect to it from outside Google Cloud?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with connecting to Spark on Dataproc from outside a cluster: Configuration and Network access. It is generally somewhat difficult and not fully supported, So I would recommend using sparklyr inside the cluster.

### Configuration

Google Cloud Dataproc runs Spark on Hadoop YARN. You actually need to use [yarn-cluster](http://spark.rstudio.com/deployment.html#cluster_deployment):

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client')
```

However you also need a `yarn-site.xml` in your `$SPARK_HOME` directory to point Spark to the right hostname.

### Network Access

While you can open ports to your IP address using [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#networks) on your Google Compute Engine network, it's not considered a good security practice. You would also need to configure YARN to use the instance's external IP address or have a way to resolve hostnames on your machine.

### Using sparklyr on Dataproc

sparklyr can be installed and run with R REPL by SSHing into the master node and running:

```
$ # Needed for the curl library
$ sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
$ R
> install.packages('sparklyr')
> library(sparklyr)
> sc <- spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client')
```

I believe RStudio Server supports SOCKS proxies, which can be set up [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/cluster-web-interfaces), but I am not very familiar with RStudio.

I use [Apache Zeppelin on Dataproc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/zeppelin) for R notebooks, but it autoloads SparkR, which I don't think plays well with sparklyr at this time.